# How to retain folder structure in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I made a program to convert the bitrate of music. The program is as follows..

```
for f in *.mp3 ;
  do lame --mp3input -b $bitrate "$f" $path_to_destination/"$f" ;
done;
```

But this works for only one folder; I have music in different folders. How to modify the code so that it can recursively make conversions happen yet retain the folder structure in the output?

Comment: Look at the `find` command, the `-exec` option. How do you want your "destination path" to work in that case? Does each subfolder have its own destination path? Or will all be converted to the same destination?

Comment: each sub folder should have its own destination..for example if there exists  a folder like linkin park and it  has 2 sub folders like "lp1" and "lp2" then the output must also be in the same structure ie. under linkin park it should have two folders lp1 and lp2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a new enough Bash (version 4.3 works; version 3.x does not), you can use:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in *.mp3 **/*.mp3
do
    lame --mp3input -b $bitrate "$file" "$path_to_destination/$file"
done
```

The `globstar` option means that the `**` notation works recursively; the `nullglob` option means that if there are no `.mp3` files in any of the subdirectories (or no sub-directories), you get nothing generated instead of a name `**/*.mp3` which would happen by default.

Because this uses globbing, it is safe even with paths or file names that contain spaces, newlines or other awkward characters.

If the sub-directories don't necessarily exist under `$path_to_destination`, then you need to create them.  Add:

```
mkdir -p $(dirname "$path_to_destination/$file")
```

before the invocation of `lame`.  This creates all the missing directories on the path leading to the target file (no error if all the directories already exist), leaving `lame` to create the file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' | while IFS= read -r src
do
   dst="$path_to_destination/$src"
   mkdir -p $(dirname "$dst")
   lame --mp3input -b $bitrate "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Comment: I am new to bash scripting.. can you please explain the code in your answer

Comment: The `find` command finds files that match `*.mp3` in the current directory or any sub-directory, and prints the names to standard output.  The `while IFS= read -r src` reads the file names one line at a time into the variable `src` (which works as long as no name in the path to a file contains a newline — it is seldom an actual problem, but it is a theoretical problem with this code), and then creates a file name (in `$dst`) and creates a directory that leads to that path (with no error if the directories already exist), and then runs the `lame` command.